# Facing a syntactic problem in Directed Acyclic Graph Python

Tags: python, directed-acyclic-graphs

Here I'm using DAG to solve Job scheduling problem.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class JobGraph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.graph = defaultdict(list)
        self.indegree = defaultdict(int)
        self.visited = set()
    
    def addEdge(u, v):
        self.graph(u).append(v)
        try:
            self.indegree[v] += 1
        except:
            self.indegree[v] = 1
        
def topologicalSort(jobs, deps, queue = [], order = [], flag = 0):
    # Write your code here.
    if flag == 0:
        g = JobGraph()
        for dep in deps:
            g.addEgde(dep[0], dep[1])
        
    for job in jobs:
        if g.indegree[job] == 0:
            queue.append(job)

    order.append(queue[0])
    root = queue[0]
    del queue[0]

    for neighbour in self.graph[root]:
        g.indegree[neighbour] -= 1
    
        if g.indegree[neighbour] == 0 and neighbour not in g.visited:
            queue.append(neighbour)
    if len(queue) == 0:
        return order
    else:
        topologicalSort(jobs, deps, queue, order, 1)
```

But the error I'm getting is

```
'JobGraph' object has no attribute 'addEgde'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tester/json_wrapper.py", line 8, in run
    actual = program.topologicalSort(inputs["jobs"][:], aelib.deepCopy(inputs["deps"]))
  File "/tester/program.py", line 20, in topologicalSort
    g.addEgde(dep[0], dep[1])
AttributeError: 'JobGraph' object has no attribute 'addEgde'
```

I know it's a syntactic issue I just don't know how to solve it

Input example

```
jobs = [1,2,3,4]
deps = [[1,2], [1,3], [3,2], [4,2], [4,3]]
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your given code is incomplete, not properly indented, and has no attempt to trace the offending value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to have other problems, but the one that's causing this error is simple and obvious.  You define a method named `addEdge` like this:

```
def addEdge(u, v):
```

but then you are calling a method named `addEgde`, like this:

```
g.addEgde(dep[0], dep[1])
```

You simply have a typo.  `addEdge != addEgde`.  You've reversed the `g` and the `d`.

BTW, the signature of that method should probably be:

```
def addEdge(self, u, v):
```